# Issue Hang on function FindByNameAsync when debug it?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on `.net core 7 blazor` web app . i face issue when working on identity user register .

when debug on function `userManager.FindByNameAsync` it hang and stuck

so I try to add watch to function `userManager.FindByNameAsync` to check reason

I get message function evaluation require all thread to run when make add

so How to solve this issue please And are that will make hang on run time applcation run on IIS .

my code generate error

```
public async Task<ResponseModel> Submit(UserDto request)
        {
          
                string roleName = request.UserRole == 1 ? "Normal" : "Admin";
                request.EmailAddress = "xyza3211116@gmail.com";
               
                var Identityuser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName);
                var newUserIdentity = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    FullName = request.UserName,
                    Email = request.EmailAddress,
                    UserName = request.UserName
                };
                var newUserResponse = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUserIdentity, "Cxx90111@7777?");
            }
```

when debug it hangs on two variables `Identityuser and newUserResponse`

and give me  function evaluation require all thread to run When make add watch to these two function `userManager.CreateAsync` and `userManager.FindByNameAsync`

so How to ignore this message and resume debugging AND see my result without hang

Updated answer
1- from debug new response

```
Id = 1127, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

2 - yes I using user manager for microsoft

```
 private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
```

name space used

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
```

**updated Answer**

my issue solved but role not solved yet

```
userManager.AddToRoleAsync // still have same issue
```

why role not added

I added .Result when create and check user and it working success

but create role not accept and still give me same issue

full code

```
public class ResponseModel
    {
        public object result { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }


        public void Success(object data)
        {
            result = data;
            message = "success";
            status = Status.success;
        }
        public void Success()
        {
            result = null;
            message = "success";
            status = Status.success;
        }

        public void Failed(string errorMsg)
        {
            result = null;
            message = errorMsg;
            status = Status.InternalServerError;
        }

        public void PartiallySucceed(string errorMsg)
        {
            result = null;
            message = "partially Succeed : " + errorMsg;
            status = Status.success;
        }
    }


    public enum Status
    {
        success = 200,
        SuccessButDataNoFound = 404,
        InternalServerError = 500,
        Unauthorized = 401,
        BadRequest = 404

    }

public async Task<ResponseModel> Submit(UserDto request)
        {
            try
            {
                string roleName = request.UserRole == 1 ? "Normal" : "Admin";
                request.EmailAddress = "Mchelaziz.ga.ba@gmail.com";
                var Identityuser =   userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.UserName).Result;
                var newUserIdentity = new IdentityUser()
                {
                    UserName = request.UserName
                };

                var newUserResponse =  userManager.CreateAsync(newUserIdentity, "Cxyz90191@1234?").Result;
                //if (newUserResponse.Succeeded)
                    var a=    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUserIdentity, roleName).Result;
                 }
```

Comment: The problem may be in the `userManager` code.  Is this your own, or someone else's?  And can you include the actual errors you get?

Comment: what you mean by Is this your own, or someone else's

Comment: i get this message function evaluation require all thread to run and i can't debug it hang on await userManager.FindByNameAsync and userManager.CreateAsync

Comment: In your code `userManager` is a variable/property that you are probably injecting.  Is it the Microsoft `UserManager` or your own?

Comment: `Id = 1127, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method..` is just the Task status if you put a break on an `await` line.  Is this Server or WASM?

Comment: thank you for reply how i know is server or WASM

Comment: I updated my answer so please can you check